# Fast solutions for $x^2+y^2+z^2=d^2$ for large $d>1000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations, computational-complexity, pythagorean-triples

I need a fast algorithm to calculate solutions to $x^2+y^2+z^2=d^2$ for $d>1000$.

I tried [Pythagorean quadruple (Alternate parametrization approach)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple#Alternate_parametrization) for $d<400$ and it isn't that fast.

**UPDATE**

```
def EfficientDivisors(n):
    factors = []
    i = 2
    while (i < sqrt(n)):
        if (n%i == 0):
            factors.append(i)
            if (i != (n/i)):
                factors.append(n//i)
        i += 1
    return factors
#alternative parameterization: a and b are both even
def fncTest4(d):
    c = 0
    nSolutionNumber = 0
    for a in range(2, d, 2):
        l = a//2
        for b in range(2, d, 2):
            m = b//2
            nTemp1 = l ** 2 + m ** 2
            factors = EfficientDivisors(nTemp1)
            for n in factors:
                if n ** 2 < nTemp1:
                    nTemp2 = (nTemp1 + n ** 2) // n
                    if d == nTemp2:
                        c = d - 2 * n
                        nSolutionNumber += 1
                        print(nSolutionNumber, ":", a, b, c, d)
                        break

fncTest4(2000) # 4 minutes
```

Comment: In terms of time-complexity I see an $O(N^3)$ solution easily via three nested loops. How fast are you looking for?

Comment: It may may easier to find a pre-computed table for solutions $x, y, z$ and $d$, then use it as a lookup table for finding corresponding values of $d$. I believe there would be pre-computed tables online

Comment: Value of $d$ is sufficiently large, for example, $10^4$. I don't know if a pre-computed table exists

Comment: Is $O(d^2)$ good enough?

Comment: @yW0K5o I would call $10^4$ rather small, but if you do need to work with large numbers then there is a reference here for a conjecturally polynomial-time (meaning $O(\log^m d)$, not $O(d^m)$) algorithm: https://mathoverflow.net/a/110277

Comment: try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple#Parametrization_of_primitive_quadruples

Comment: Will, I did it but it is slow.

Comment: @yW0K5o It doesn't look inherently slow to me.  But there is enough generality in the description that you could have a very slow implementation of the concept.

Comment: @ErickWong, I added my code. Can it be improved?

Comment: I assume you want $(a,b,c)>0$. Are you after solutions or primitive solutions?

Comment: @OldPeter Yes, I want the primitive unique solutions. $(a,b,c)>0$ . Then I use permutations to get all solutions (order with signs).

Comment: So $gcd(a,b,c)=1$ ?

Comment: Some of unique solutions have $gcd(a,b,c)=1$, some are not.

Comment: I've just ran $d=1001$ to $2000$ in under 60 seconds, producing $168505$ solutions, using VB6. If this is fast enough, I'll post my method tomorrow.

Comment: OK. It is fast enough. Looking forward to see your solution tomorrow. Thank you !!!

Comment: @yW0K5o I think your simplest solution can be found in another post about [matching sides of Pythagorean triples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880890/are-there-any-2-primitive-pythagorean-triples-who-share-a-common-leg/3238431#3238431).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s the outline.

WLOG, $a>=b>=c$.

Then $a$ has a maximum value of $d-1$ and a minimum value of $\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{3}}$, rounded down.

For each $a$, calculate $u=d^2-a^2$

Then maximum $b$ is $\sqrt{u}$ rounded up, but also $<=a$ and minimum $b$ is $\sqrt{\frac{u}{2}}$, rounded down.

For each $b$, calculate $v=u-b^2$

When $v$ is a square, $c=\sqrt{v}$ and we have a solution.

Good luck with your project.
Please let me know if you need any more details.

I’ll add the VB6 code, if I ever find out how to do it.

**Some test results, $(c,b,a,d)$**

$$(20,28,29,45)$$
$$(15,30,30,45)$$
$$(6,30,33,45)$$
$$(20,20,35,45)$$
$$(4,28,35,45)$$
$$(16,20,37,45)$$
$$(13,16,40,45)$$
$$(8,19,40,45)$$
$$(5,20,40,45)$$
$$(6,15,42,45)$$
$$(5,8,44,45)$$
$$(22,31,34,51)$$
$$(17,34,34,51)$$
$$(24,27,36,51)$$
$$(3,36,36,51)$$
$$(14,31,38,51)$$
$$(1,34,38,51)$$
$$(14,17,46,51)$$
$$(1,22,46,51)$$
$$(14,14,47,51)$$
$$(10,10,49,51)$$
$$(2,14,49,51)$$
$$(1,10,50,51)$$
$$(480,600,640,1000)$$
$$(192,640,744,1000)$$
$$(424,480,768,1000)$$
$$(280,576,768,1000)$$
$$(224,600,768,1000)$$
$$(24,640,768,1000)$$
$$(360,480,800,1000)$$
$$(168,576,800,1000)$$
$$(192,480,856,1000)$$
$$(352,360,864,1000)$$
$$(152,480,864,1000)$$
$$(96,480,872,1000)$$
$$(96,360,928,1000)$$
$$(168,224,960,1000)$$
$$(960,1200,1280,2000)$$
$$(384,1280,1488,2000)$$
$$(848,960,1536,2000)$$
$$(560,1152,1536,2000)$$
$$(448,1200,1536,2000)$$
$$(48,1280,1536,2000)$$
$$(720,960,1600,2000)$$
$$(336,1152,1600,2000)$$
$$(384,960,1712,2000)$$
$$(704,720,1728,2000)$$
$$(304,960,1728,2000)$$
$$(192,960,1744,2000)$$
$$(192,720,1856,2000)$$
$$(336,448,1920,2000)$$

Comment: Peter, how could you verify if your method gives the same solutions which described in Wikipedia[Pythagorian quadruple]?

Comment: I've tested small values against those independently produced on a spreadsheet, and I've used this general method for years. If you give me a value for $d<46340$ I'll post the values for you to check against your results. Please will you tell me how to add my code, as per the grey box in your question?

Comment: With $d<30$ my code produces the 31 solutions shown in your link, plus 18 others with $gcd(a,b,c)>1$

Comment: Peter, I use Chrome browser. When you edit your answer put/click your VB6 code in curly braces.

Comment: To verify your solutions use d=50 it gives 2 unique solutions, and canbe verified in this link https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PowersRepresentations%5B50%5E2,3,2%5D [discard 0-solutions]

Comment: Here's the image how to add your code: https://image.ibb.co/h6AOox/code.jpg

Comment: Program produces $(c,b,a)=(24,30,32),(18,24,40) for $d=50$. It's easy to change if you want the results with zero given by your link.

Comment: Try other value for test 45, 51, 1000, 2000.

Comment: I implemented your method and it gives less solutions than Wikepedia's one. Could you also provide proof why your method can find all solutions?

Comment: Test results added to answer. Please give examples of missing results. I'm still unable to add my code despite many attempts; the code could help. I'll look at a proof.

Comment: Test for 45:
My code:
[ 4 28 35 ]
[ 6 30 33 ]
[ 6 15 42 ]
[ 8 19 40 ]
[ 5 8 44 ]
[ 16 20 37 ]
[ 13 16 40 ]
[ 20 20 35 ]
[ 20 28 29 ]
[ 5 20 40 ]
[ 15 30 30 ]

Comment: Test for 45:
Peter's code:
`def fncTestPeterMethod(d):
    c = 0
    dSquared = d ** 2
    nAUpperRange = d - 1
    nALowerRange = int(sqrt(dSquared/3))
    for a in range(nALowerRange, nAUpperRange, 1):
        u = dSquared - a**2
        nBUpperRange = int(sqrt(u))
        nBLowerRange = int(sqrt(u/2))
        for b in range(nBLowerRange, nBUpperRange, 1):
            v = u - b**2
            nTemp1 = CheckThePefectSquare(v)
            if nTemp1 != -1:
                c = nTemp1
                print(a, b, c)`

Comment: Test for 45:Peter's code results: 
[ 20 28 29 ][ 15 30 30 ][ 20 20 35 ][ 16 20 37 ][ 13 16 40 ][ 8 19 40 ][ 6 15 42 ]

Comment: I fixed my errors it seems like your method works !

Comment: Yes, I've used this method for more than ten years, and would be devastated to find it flawed. Well done for correcting your code. Perhaps you would care to up-vote my answer?